# "puppet agent --test" on client machine aren't getting manifest from the Puppet master server

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet

**Issue**

So I have two AWS instances: a Puppet master and a Puppet client. When I run `sudo puppet agent --test` on my client, the tasks defined in my master's manifest didn't apply to the client instance.

**Where I am right now**

- puppetmaster is installed on the master instance
- puppet is installed on client instance
- Master just finished signing my client's certificate. No errors were displayed
- Master has a `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`
- Client's puppet.conf file has a `server=dns_of_master` line
- My Puppet version is 5.4.0. I'm using the default manifest configuration.
- Here's the guide that I'm following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-puppet-code-manifests-and-modules. The only changes are the site.pp content and that I'm using AWS.
- If it helps, here's my AWS instances' AMI: **ami-06d51e91cea0dac8d**

**Details**

Here's the content on my master's `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`:

```
node default {
        package { 'nginx':
        ensure => installed
        }
        service { 'nginx':
        ensure => running,
        require => Package['nginx']
        }
        file { '/tmp/hello_world':
        ensure => present,
        content => 'Hello, World!'
        }
}
```

The file has a permission of 777.

Here's the ouput when I run `sudo puppet agent --test`. This is after I ran `sudo puppet agent --enable`:

```
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Caching catalog for my_client_dns
Info: Applying configuration version '1578968015'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.02 seconds
```

I have looked at other StackOverflow posts with this issue. I know that my catalog is not getting applied due to the lack of status messages and the quick time. Unfortunately, the solutions didn't apply to my case:

- My `site.pp` is named correctly and in the correct file path `/etc/puppet/manifests`
- I didn't touch my master's `puppet.conf` file
- I tried restarting the server with `sudo systemctl` but nothing happens

Comment: What version(s) of Puppet are you using?  `/etc/puppet/manifests` is *not* (by default) the correct location for your site manifest in any version of Puppet that is still supported.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am currently running v5.4.0

Comment: ... which *is* still supported at this time.  The default location for your site manifest in that and later versions of Puppet, for environment "production" to which your node is assigned, is `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed the issue. The guide that I was following required an older version of Ubuntu (16.4, rather than 18.4 as I'm using). This needs a different AMI than the one that I used to create the instances.